# Disable muliple checkout in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I need to configure TFS 2012 source control, so that only one person can checkout/edit a file at one time.  I tried to disable multiple chec out from TEAM --> TEAM PROJECT SETTINGS --> SOURCE CONTROL as follows, but it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

[image]

Also, is there a way to make the locktype deafault to "Check Out - Prevent other users from checking out and checking in"?
[image]

Comment: Local workspaces are the default in 2012.  As that screenshot indicates, Multiple check-out is always enabled in local workspaces.  Did you turn local workspaces off everywhere?

Comment: Yes, I changed local workspace to server and tested with another developer.  We both were able to checkout and make changes.